# Java Bouncycastle Generate Ed25519 OpenSSH Private Key File Failing

Tags: java, bouncycastle, openssh, ed25519

I've been trying to programatically generate OpenSSH host keys in my Java application, but I'm unable to get a working Ed25519 key in the OpenSSH v1 key format. My current thought is that there's a problem with OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil, but I'm not sure how to verify that. Here's my current attempt:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil;

import java.util.Base64;

...

Ed25519PrivateKeyParamters keyParamters = new Ed25519PrivateKeyParamters(new SecureRandom());
byte[] encodedPrivateKey = OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil.encodePrivateKey(keyParameters);
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedPrivateKey));
```

The output looks like what I'm expecting (similar to the results of an ssh-keygen -t ed25519), but when I put the results into /etc/ssh/sshd_host_ed25519_key (and the corresponding public key into /etc/ssh/sshd_host_ed25519_key.pub), I get the following error from sshd in /var/log/messages:

```
auth.err: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/sshd_host_ed25519_key
```

I'm using the following:

- centos   7.6
- java     1.8.0_212
- openssh  7.4p1-16.e17
- bouncycastle 1.63

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Although the body content looks right to me (for unencrypted), your code doesn't put linebreaks in the base64 and add the dashes-BEGIN and dashes-END lines as ssh-keygen does. **BEGIN/END are definitely required**; I'm not sure if linebreaks are, but you can get them easily with `Base64.getMimeEncoder()` instead of the default Basic encoder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I put the Begin and End tags as well as the line breaks on manually when I was testing it, so I don't think that's necessarily the problem.

Comment: Can you add an example of a key with the problem (which you don't and won't use for any real data, obviously)?

Comment: Turns out it was just a bug. They've already patched it (thanks BC team). Should be out in the next release. I've tested it in the beta release and it seems to be working fine.